# How to check stereoscopic 3D mode in Delphi

Tags: delphi, windows-7, 3d, blu-ray

I'm using Delphi to develop an application for the control of a third-party player that can play bluray 3D movie on Windows 7.
Is there a way to determinate if current display is in stereoscopic mode? In other way, I need to check if video player is playing a 3D video and the stereoscopic mode is enabled.

Comment: Are you checked the MSDN documentation [Direct3D stereoscopic 3D sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct3D-111-Simple-Stereo-9b2b61aa)?

Comment: seems that it is only for windows-8...